# Python Web Browser Engine

Tags: python, c++, google-chrome, browser

I'm thinking of making a toy web browser in Python and I don't want to use Webkit, I'd like to see if I can make a web browser including the engine for it. My question is, would Python be fast enough to write a web browser engine, obviously Python would be slower than C++ in benchmarks, but in terms of actual noticeable differences in speed would there be any difference?

Also, even though this is a "toy" project, I'd still like my browser to render Javascript and HTML5 which is why I'm wondering if Python would be a good tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen http://grail.sourceforge.net/ ?  It's ancient, but it's a web browser written in Python.